# compiling ImageMagick core in c

Tags: c, imagemagick

I am trying to compile simple imageMagick (MagickCore). I am using the C interface. The code I am trying to compile is the first example this site [MagickCore API](http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/script/magick-core.php)!

The configuration and installation of the [library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) goes perfect. the "make check" command result all check to "PASS".

I also able to run operations on the command line, example:

```
    convert logo: test.gif
```

Now, I want to use the C programming API. I just start with an example provided on [MagickCore API](http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/script/magick-core.php)!

I try to compile it using the following command: (which itself is provided on the same site as the source code):

```
    cc -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickCore` test.c
```

but it results the following error (I try to look around and it is taking my time).

```
    fatal error: MagickCore/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory
```

any suggestion please?

please note that I have also set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, so ImageMagick is now in my default system path: **export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig**

Comment: looks like this one solves my problem : 

gcc `Magick-config --cflags --cppflags` demo.c `Magick-config --ldflags --libs`

more [here](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/ImageMagick/www/api.html). cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try use the compiler argument `-I path_to_headers`, specifying the path of Magick headers (or something others).